# Python：イテレータクラスでインデックスを返したい

Tags: python

Python2.7でイテレータクラスを作りました。
インデックスを返すようにしたかったため、タプルで返すようにしたのですが、インデックスが不要な場合、エラーとなってしまいます。

これをエラーなく、インデックスが不要な場合にも対応する方法を共有します。

```
class ItTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.list = [10, 20, 30]

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = 0
        self.max = len(self.list)
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.index >= self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        output_index = self.index
        output = self.list[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return output_index, output


def main():
    # OK
    for index, x in ItTest():
        print(x+1)
    # エラー
    for x in ItTest():
        print(x+1)
```

Comment: ん，しかし Python 2 では上記のコードでエラーが出ないですよ．`10 20 30 (1,10) (2,20) (3,30)` が出力されます．

Comment: @Yosh あ、すみませんこのコードではエラーにならないですね。要は受け取る変数xに異なる型が入ってしまうため、参照時等にエラーが出ます。エラーとなるように演算しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純に`enumerate`を使えばよかったです。
リスト等にしか使用できないと思い込みました･･･

```
class ItTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.list = [10, 20, 30]

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = 0
        self.max = len(self.list)
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.index >= self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        output = self.list[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return output # indexは返さない


def main():
    # OK
    for index, x in enumerate(ItTest()):
        print(x+1)
    # OK
    for x in ItTest():
        print(x+1)
```

Comment: 念のための情報ですが、`enumerate`を使用するためには`self.index`が必要なわけでありません。`enumerate`内でインデックスを管理しているようです。

Comment: 自己解決されたようですが, 公式ドキュメントにある enumerate 関数の引数の制約を引用しておきます.

「シーケンスか iterator か、あるいはその他のイテレーションをサポートする何らかのオブジェクトでなければなりません。」

http://docs.python.jp/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate より